# Make a table like this in ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net

So I'm using a GridView and it should look like this, but it doesn't really work.
How do I need to use the CSS to make it look like that. And I'm using a SqlDataSource so I can't customize every td or tr. 
[image]

Comment: I've already got something with borders on every site but because I'm using an sqldatasource, I can't just customize ervery single row

Comment: You don't have to customise every row. Look up the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo classes.

Comment: @MrLister So I am currently using the child selector but how can I remove the line on the right. Is there any last-child which I can use horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use what Mr Lister says, unless you need support for IE8 too. Then use the following in your CSS file for the vertical lines except first:

```
.yourClassName th + th,
.yourClassName td + td 
{
    border-left: thin solid black;
}
```

For your horizontal lines use something like this (depending on how you do border-collapse do it or tr or td):

```
.yourClassName tr + tr td
{
    border-top: thin solid black;
}
```